# VS code parse error ignored in some components

Tags: html, angular

Currently working on an html template using angular, and I have this code:

```
 <a mat-list-item class="side-link" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" [routerLink]="[{outlets: { agent-sidebar: ['agent-manage-clients'] } }]"><i class="fas fa-user mr-3"></i>Clients</a>
```

As you can see, there's nothing wrong with the code. However, doing an `ng build` produces an error whereas the compiler is looking for a missing `:` token where I think is unnecessary.

1. Why does my compiler keep looking for a 'missing' token even though I have closed the braces correctly?
2. This is funny to me because this is a copy pasted working code in a different component and only produced an error when I pasted it in this new component. So why isn't it producing the same error in the other component?

Comment: Does the module of this component have any RouterModule or RoutingModule? Maybe the module of the component where this code works does have it, so it would be good to compare those

Comment: @Jelle Yes this component does have RouterModule. I've double checked and they both have the same type of routing, just different path names of course.

Comment: Could you try it with "agent-sidebar" or agentSidebar. The dash might be causing issues here

Comment: Hi @Jelle, ya I just figured that out. I've already posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, I've fixed this bug of mine by changing the name of my router-outlet. It turns out that naming my outlet `agent-sidebar` with the token `-` messes up the compiler somehow. So after almost half a day of work, I've changed this:

`[routerLink]="[{outlets: { agent-sidebar: ['agent-manage-clients'] } }]"`

to this:

`[routerLink]="[{outlets: { agentSidebar: ['agent-manage-clients'] } }]"`

and compiler is now working properly.